# Looping through adjacent cells then down the rows in R

Tags: c++, r, excel, vba

I'm relatively new to R and have a .xlsx spreadsheet I'm trying to manipulate. I've imported my spreadsheet into R it has close to 30 columns and 10000 rows of data. What I need to be able to do is loop through just 4 of the columns and check if any 3 or 2 adjacent cells have the same values.

If they do I want to count this instance.

I imagine that writing a for loop where I compare column a1 to column b1 to column c1 etc then store the number of adjacent cells with the same value then loop to the next row.
I could do this in C++ but I'm just not used to R's syntax.

If someone could just give me a bit of guidance I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: can you put a reproducing example? (your input data.frame and the wanted output)

Answer (score 2):

`diff` is usefull here:

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:4, 20, TRUE), ncol = 4))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  4  3  2  4
#2  4  3  3  4
#3  2  1  4  1
#4  4  3  2  2
#5  3  3  2  3
sum(apply(DF, 1, function(x) sum(c(1, diff(x) != 0)) < 4))
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Aah thank you for your help! One more question I have blanks separating groups of data in the 4 columns which is messing with my analysis. Can I choose to ignore the blanks? I tried na.omit() but I think that may move my cells up or down and move adjacent cells apart?

Comment: That depends on how you'd like to handle `NA` values. Should `c(1, 2, NA, 2)` be `TRUE` or `FALSE`? What about `c(1, NA, NA, 2)`?